# Yii2 Migrate Command Programmatically

Tags: php, database, console, yii2, migrate

I want to `migrate` `up`/`down` the database using the `code` instead of the console window. I have looked into the `framework`. I have tried the following code:

```
$runner = new yii\console\Application([
                                          'id'       => 'auto-migrate',
                                          'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__)
                                      ]);        

    $runner->runAction('migrate');
    ob_start();
    return htmlentities(ob_get_clean(), null, Yii::$app->charset);
```

It gives the `Internal Server Error`. And doesn't even migrates the files to the database.
But if the directory doesn't exists, it creates the directory. It is behaving the way it should but if the migration file exist in that same directory it gives `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Please give us some more context. Are you trying to invoke a console application in a webapp here in order to apply migrations automagically?

Comment: @DaSourcerer Yes. That is what I'm trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do that over php function [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), but if you really want to do it by creating new application instance then you should be able to do it like this.

**Case 1** - not very good idea

```
//Define, if you want to capture output
defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://input', 'r'));
defined('STDOUT') or define('STDOUT', fopen('php://output', 'w'));
//Create new console app, if you do not run it from root namespace you should use '\yii\console\Application'
$runner = new \yii\console\Application([
    'id'       => 'auto-migrate',
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers', //for migrate command it should not matter but for other cases you must specify otherwise applocation cannot find your controllers
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__ . '/../../console/config'), //This must point to your console config directory, when i run this in frontend sitecontroller i must add '/../../console/config',
    'components' => [
                'db' => [//If you want to call migrate you probably need some database component
                    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
                ],
            ],
]);        
ob_start();
try
{
    $runner->runAction('migrate/up');
}
catch(\Exception $ex)
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
return htmlentities(ob_get_clean(), null, Yii::$app->charset);
```

And result in my case:

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.1) No new migration found. Your system is up-to-date.
```

**Case 2**

```
    ob_start();
    try
    {
        $output = Array();
        exec(__DIR__ . '/../../yii migrate/up', $output);
        echo implode("\n", $output);
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    return htmlentities(ob_get_clean(), null, Yii::$app->charset);
```

And result in my case:

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.1) No new migration found. Your system is up-to-date.
```

Comment: The answer that you have provided still works in the console context and not in the Web app context.

Comment: @Abhimanyu please add more details about what you are thinking, as both my case's was called through Web App. and runned through http://localhost/yii2/frontend/web/index.php?r=test/console what creates webapp first $application = new yii\web\Application($config); So in test controller i had action console where i runned both testcases. So i actually created console app in 1st case inside web app.

Comment: @Abhimanyu if you want to do it with web app only then you probably should just create similar controller like BaseMigrateController in yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers and let it extend yii\web\Controller instead of  yii\console\Controller

Comment: With your solution the view was not getting rendered.

Comment: @Abhimanyu in case 1 view cannot be rendered because creating new console application overwrites some static values in yii application, so you actually swap your original web app to console app. So in case you want to render view you should re-create webapp with desired conf or use some redirecting, main reason why i suggested to use case 2.

Comment: @Abhimanyu in case 2 you can render view easily. View was not rendered because in case 2 there is return htmlentities(ob_get_clean(), null, Yii::$app->charset); - that i copied from your code as i expected that you did not want to render view. if you replace it example $this->render('view_name', Array('result' => ob_get_clean())) then view will be rendered.

Answer (score 5):

```
\Yii::$app->runAction('migrate', ['migrationPath' => '@yii/rbac/migrations/']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create Console Application with loading Console config to run migration:

```
public function actionMigrate()
{
    // Keep current application
    $oldApp = \Yii::$app;
    // Load Console Application config
    $config = require \Yii::getAlias('@app'). '/config/console.php';
    new \yii\console\Application($config);
    $result = \Yii::$app->runAction('migrate', ['migrationPath' => '@app/migrations/', 'interactive' => false]);
    // Revert application
    \Yii::$app = $oldApp;
    return;
}
```

Above sample code is for yii2-app-basic template, you could change path for yii2-app-advanced template.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, I use this solution. I only implement the `migrate/up` case. To execute any other `migrate` command, you must configure the parameters of `runAction()`.

```
use yii\console\controllers\MigrateController;

/*Suppose that config is an array with the following structure
[
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => "$dsn",
    'username' => "$username",
    'password' => "$password",
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]
*/
public function migrateUp($config){
    $migrate = new MigrateController('migrate', \Yii::$app);
    /*The name of the table for keeping applied migration information*/
    $migrate->migrationTable = 'migration';
    /*At least one of `migrationPath` or `migrationNamespaces` should be specified.
    For this example I use `migrationNamespaces` to find a specific set of migrations I want to execute.*/
    $migrate->migrationNamespaces = [
        'app\modules\v1\migrations'
    ];
    $migrate->migrationPath = null;
    /*The DB connection object to use when applying migrations*/
    $migrate->db = $config;
    /*Run migrations without asking questions*/
    $migrate->interactive = false;
    /*The individual commands ran within the migration will not be output to the console*/
    $migrate->compact = true;
    /*php://temp is a read-write stream that allow temporary data to be stored in a file-like wrapper */
    define('STDOUT', $fp= fopen('php://temp', 'r+'));
    /*run migrate/up */
    $status = $migrate->runAction('up');
    /*Rewind the position of the file pointer*/
    rewind($fp);
    $migrationOutput = stream_get_contents($fp);
    if (isset($status)){
        ob_get_clean();
        return ['Errors when executing migrations', $migrationOutput];
    }
    return ['Everything ok', $migrationOutput];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shared Hosting using Yii2's Advanced Template - Console app within web app**
I have successfully applied the above code with a few tweaks.

Single domain multi/web with subfolders eg. company1/web

```
multi/web/index.php
         /.htaccess
         /assets
         /common/config/main.php
         /common/config/bootstrap.php
         /config/main-local.php has 
                /only db and urlManager baseUrl=''
         /console/config/main.php
         /frontend/config/main.php
         /images
         /company1/web/assets
         /company1/web/images
         /company1/web/.htaccess
         /company1/web/index.php
         /company1/config/main-local.php

         /company2/web/assets
         /company2/web/images
         /company2/web/.htaccess
         /company2/web/index.php
         /company2/config/main-local.php 

         /company3/web/assets
         /company3/web/images
         /company3/web/.htaccess
         /company3/web/index.php
         /company3/config/main-local.php         
         /vendor
```

Each company config main-local contains only the db and UrlManager components. The baseUrl of the UrlManager eg. '/company3/web/'

multi/web index.php is configured as follows:

```
<?php

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
defined('YII_CONSOLE') or define('YII_CONSOLE', false);

//vendors from composer.json
require (__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

//yii framework
require(__DIR__  . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

//common frontend bower and installer aliases
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php');

//empty
require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    //vendor path, twilio, paypal
    require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php'),

    //db=installer , urlmanager swiftmailer
    require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php'),

    //etc... db and UrlManager Removed into above
    require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/main.php'),

    //cookie validation key
    require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/main-local.php')
);
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
?>
```

Each company's subfolder's index.php is configured as follows:

```````
<?php

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
defined('YII_CONSOLE') or define('YII_CONSOLE', false);

require(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))  . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
//aliases eg. common frontend bower
require(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/common/config/bootstrap.php');
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(

    //vendor path components ...rbac
    require(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/common/config/main.php'),

    //customer's  database and urlmanager and swiftmailer taken out of frontend/config/main.php
    require(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/main-local.php'),

    //excluding components db and urlmanager included in above
    require(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/config/main.php'),

    //cookie validation key
    require(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/config/main-local.php')
);
//
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
``````
I have created an action in my Site controller to perform the console migration within the actionMigrateto_company_database.


<?php

public function actionMigrateto_company_database()
    {
        ob_start();
        defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://input', 'r'));
        defined('STDOUT') or define('STDOUT', fopen('php://output', 'w'));
        defined('STDERR') or define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));
        $oldApp = \Yii::$app;
        // Load Console Application config
        $config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
        //migration namespaces and 
        //namespaces included in individual
        //migration files
        require \Yii::getAlias('@console'). '/config/main.php',    
        //vendor path components ...rbac
        require \Yii::getAlias('@common').'/config/main.php',
        //database
        require (dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) .dirname(Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl). '/config/main-local.php'));    
        $runner = new \yii\console\Application($config);
        $runner->runAction('migrate',['db','interactive' => 0]);
        fclose(\STDOUT);
        fclose(\STDIN);
        fclose(\STDERR);
        \Yii::$app = $oldApp;
        return ob_get_clean();
      }
?>

Adjust the frontend\views\layouts\main.php with 

if (Yii::$app->UrlManager->baseUrl === '') and 
 if (Yii::$app->UrlManager->baseUrl <> '') statements.

.htaccess files are all as follows: 
`````
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
`````
```````